# How to check if a string already exists in mysql (All word order options)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say i check if

```
 $strig = "how can i do this";
```

already exists in my database with all words order options?
Like:
"how i can do this"
or
"i do this can how"
...
...

my database looks like:

```
 id    string
  1    how can i do this
  2    hello how are you
  3    how i can do this world
  4    another title
 etc   etc
```

Thanks

Comment: IMPOSSIBRU to answer without you stelling us how your database looks. And what kind of data is in there. and if it's ok if there are  more words. etc etc

Comment: hi, i fix the question with more details, yes there are more words like the 3

Comment: What are the hits in this example? 1 and 3 or only 1, because there is "world" in 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky problem if you want to fix this in sql only, but that aside:

As @er.anuragjain says, you can do a query with `LIKE %word%`, but you would also get a hit on your example '3'.

So if you have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
     column LIKE '%how%' 
AND  column LIKE '%can%'
AND  column LIKE '%i%'
AND  column LIKE '%do%'
AND  column LIKE '%this%'
```

Then you also get number 3. So you need to check if there are no **other** words. You can do this by checking the word count (if you have 5 words and all of your words are in there, you are done.).

Checking wordcount is not trivial, but there is a trick. From several sources*:

```
SELECT LENGTH(total_words) - LENGTH(REPLACE(total_words, ' ', ''))+1
FROM tbl_test;
```

should do the trick. So check the `LIKE`'s, and check the wordcount, and you're done. But I'm not really sure this is a pretty sollution :)

- http://www.webtechquery.com/index.php/2010/03/count-number-of-words-in-mysql-mysql-words-count/
  and http://www.mwasif.com/2008/12/count-number-of-words-in-a-mysql-column/
  (random google hits :) )

Answer (score 3):

The number of possible combinations is `n!` (120 in your sample) so checking if this string already exists is quite complex task.
I would recommend to use the following algorithm:

- Add new column `StringHash` to your table
- On insert order your string (e.g. alphabetically), calculate its hash and store in `StringHash`: 
  `"how can i do this" => "can do how i this" => md5("can+do+how+i+this")`
- If you want to check if a certain string exists in the db then again calculate its hash as described above and query the db on `YourTable.StringHash`

Answer (score 0):

you can ask if the string where you are searching in, contains: `"how" and "can" and "I" and "do" and "this"` 
something like this:(I don't know the syntax in mysql but see the concept)

```
    if(string.contain("how")&&
       string.contain("can")&&
       string.contain("I")&&
       string.contain("do")&&
       string.contain("this"))
     {
       //you find the string
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

should be the wildcard call in mysql

```
select * From tablename Where columnname LIKE '%how%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql then try this..

```
select * from tablename where columnname Like '%how%' AND columnname LIKE '%can%' AND columnname LIKE '%I'% AND columnname LIKE '%DO'% AND columnname LIKE '%This'%;
```

Here if u have dynamic value in `$string` then first convert it into an array spliting by space.then create a `$condition` varriable from the array and append that in     `select * from tablename` where and run that query.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex first crate a function like this

```
public function part($str){
    $str = str_replace('‌',' ',$str);
    $arr = explode(' ',$str);
    $rejex = '';
    foreach($arr as $item){
        $rejex .= "(?=.*$item)";
    }
    return $rejex;
}
```

and then use sql regex

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP ".part($str);
```